# How do I find the average age of users based on value of another column?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset for health procedures with each patient listed under Index_Num. Most patients are listed several times as they have had several services. There is a column with their age.

There is another column called Portal_Use, which says "Yes" or "No" based on whether the user is a portal user.

The question I am trying to visualize in Tableau is the Average Age of Portal Users.

I created a group of the Index_Num, but don't know where to go from there. I'm essentially looking for a bar chart that has one bar for portal users and one bar for non portal users with the average age. This would be very easy if there weren't multiple rows per patient.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, make it up if necessary, in the same format as your data source? That would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation I have used below data to generate the sample workbook.

[image: Source Data]

1. Use your Portal_Use flag as a Columns
2. Add Age as an AVG value in Row section
3. From Show me section select the Type of Bar char you needed

Above will give you desired results as per below.
[image: Workbook]

I hope this helps!!!